# How to zoom and minimize text in Ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am developing an app on Ionic 3. How can I maximize and minimize text data?

[image]

Comment: is there a button you'll use to max/min the font size? Will the user controll the font size? please be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

zoom and minimize feature is not available in-build in Ionic but you can increase or decrease the font size with Media queries in scss.

```
#fontSize{
    @media (min-height: 700px) {
  font-size: 2rem !important;
  }
  @media (max-height: 600px){
  font-size: 1.4rem !important;  
  }
  @media (min-height: 600px) and (max-height: 700px){
  font-size: 1.8rem !important;
  }
}
```

You can also try to change the font size in component on user interaction using [Ionic gestures](https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#gestures)

```
document.getElementById("bar").style.fontSize=2rem;
```